# Rails: Avoid N+1 issue with scope

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a N+1 problem when trying to display stats on a list of workshops

I think it comes from my "is_enabled" scope

Here is what's in the view

```
 - users.sort_by{ |u| u.workshops.is_enabled.size }.reverse.each do |u|
  - u.lastname.capitalize
  - u.workshops.is_enabled.size
```

And in my scope in workshop.rb

```
scope :is_enabled, -> { where(enabled: true).joins(:theme).merge(Theme.is_enabled) }
```

a theme has workshops

Sorry if the formating and phrasing is wrong, i'm new to stackoverflow and programming.

Comment: I believe `u.workshops` is where you get the *N+1* issue

Comment: I don't think so because when I remove the "is_enabled" scope I don't have the n+1 issue

Comment: Do you any method with the same name in the `Workshop` model because `scopes` can only be called on *classes*. And I believe `is_enabled` in `u.workshops.is_enabled` should be an *instance method* that is declared somewhere in your `Workshop` model

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but I don't have any method called is_enabled is the `Workshop` model. the scope `is_enabled` in the `Theme` model is this `scope :is_enabled, -> { where(enabled: true, status: STATUS_APPROVED) }`

Comment: Ok so basically I should remove my scope and make it an instance method that checks the same thing ?

Comment: `users = User.includes(:workshops)`

Comment: That's already there :(

Comment: try User.includes(workshops: [:themes]) ?